# Return the most frequent IP address from the logs

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list of logs with IP addresses in the following format.

```
lines = ["10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24", "10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24", "10.0.0.2 - GET 2020-08-20"]
```

Return the most frequent IP address from the logs. The retuned IP address value must be in a string format. If multiple IP addresses have the count equal to max count, then return the address as a comma-separated string with IP addresses in sorted order.

Can someone explain to me how to solve this in python using hashmap?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this? What program have you been able to write that comes closest to what you are supposed to write now?

Comment: I think you need to convert the list into a dict by extracting the IPs. The keys will be IPs and count of occurrence will be value. Then take the max value. What have you tried so far to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

### Finding the most occurring element in a list using a hashmap

---

***line 3:*** Count the occurrences of items in lines using dictionary comprehension and the count() method.

```
lines = ["10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24", "10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24", "10.0.0.2 - GET 2020-08-20"]

cnt = {x:lines.count(x) for x in set(lines)}
n = max(cnt.values())
res = [k for k in cnt if cnt[k] == n]
print(res)

>['10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `multimode`:

```
from statistics import multimode

lines = ["10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24",
         "10.0.0.1 - GET 2020-08-24",
         "10.0.0.2 - GET 2020-08-20",
         "10.0.0.2 - GET 2020-08-20"]

ips = (line.split()[0] for line in lines)
print(','.join(sorted(multimode(ips))))
```